# Paste function doesn't work for files in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio

I have two notebooks, and both have RStudio. When I try to use fread module from library data.table I need to specify the file **(.csv in this case)** for read and usually I just use Control+C and Control+V to the first argument from function. In one of these notebooks works perfectly, but in another it just don't paste anything ..... I need to activate a module or something I'm my RStudio?

```
library(data.table)
test <- fread("does not paste anything", sep=";", dec=",")
```

Comment: Are you saying you can’t copy and paste into the console window in rstudio?

Comment: Both, console and script window :(